# ArrayList.get() function in Java requires int for index instead of the desired long

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LargestPrimeFactor {
    private static long maxNum;

    public LargestPrimeFactor(long maxNum) {
        LargestPrimeFactor.maxNum = maxNum;
        ArrayList<Long> listOfPrimes = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfPrimes.add(2L);

        for (long i = 3; i < maxNum / 2; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1 && isPrime(i)) {
                listOfPrimes.add(i);
            }
        }

//        for (long i = 0; i < listOfPrimes.size(); i++) {
//            System.out.println(listOfPrimes.get((int) i));
//        }

        for (long i = listOfPrimes.size() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (maxNum % ((long) listOfPrimes.get(i)) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Max Prime Factor is: " + listOfPrimes.get(i));
                break;
            }

//            System.out.println(listOfPrimes.get((int) i));
        }
    }

    private boolean isPrime(long num) {
        for (long i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem in my code is following: enen if I autobox to `<Long>`, Java requires to cast to `int` when I use `listOfPrimes::get`. It is not desired because the numbers I would work with would be out of scope. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this loop

```
for (long i = listOfPrimes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (maxNum % ((long) listOfPrimes.get(i)) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Max Prime Factor is: " + listOfPrimes.get(i));
        break;
    }
}
```

You should change the type of `i` from `long` to `int`. This is not saying that the numbers in `listOfPrimes` must be `int`, it only says that the count of elements in `listOfPrimes` must be representable with a 32bit signed integer.

Indeed, `listOfPrimes.size()` returns an integer, not a long. In Java, the length of an array is *always* specified by an `int`. Hence an array cannot hold more elements than an `int` can count. As a result, an `ArrayList` cannot hold more elements either.

Moreover, the `Collection.size()` method returns an `int`, so that none of the classes that implement the `Collection` interface can hold more values.

*Edit*: As mentioned by user16320675 in the comments, collections can hold more elements than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You just have to be careful about what `size()` returns in those cases: it returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE` rather than the actual size.

Comment: @user16320675 Indeed a bit confusing. I guess it makes kind of sense: you *can* have collections that have more elements, you just cannot query their size reliably (or random access all their elements). They could still be useful since you could iterate over them, perform lookups etc. But indeed I did not know about this additional sentence in the docs. Thanks for bringing it up!